# COPY of packages failing in docker file

Tags: docker

I have a dockerfile that has this line, I am trying to remove this hardcoded value from this line.

This is the original line and when i do docker build, this works
`COPY --from=stage1  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`

whereas when i try to replace with this line, the build fails

`ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10`

`COPY --from=stage1  /usr/local/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/site-packages/  /usr/local/lib/python${PYTHON_VERSION}/site-packages/`

The error here is `COPY failed: stat usr/local/lib/python3.10.13/site-packages/: file does not exist`

when i checked in the `stage1` docker image, the python files exist in `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/`

This is my entire docker file

```
FROM base-image:tag as stage1

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.10

RUN  gcc \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && rm -f requirements.txt 

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/
FROM baseimage:tag as stage2
COPY --from=stage1  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/  /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/
COPY . /my_dir
WORKDIR /my_dir

RUN chmod +x my_script.sh
```

Comment: Do you send in a python_version when building the image? If so, it will override the one specified in the dockerfile.

Comment: no i am not passing any version while building the docker file, so i dont know how come the version is changing to 3.10.13 instead of 3.10

Comment: For this sort of multi-stage build setup, I wonder if using a virtual environment would work better.  Then you'd control the path in both containers, and it wouldn't have to depend on the Python version.

Comment: Your question is very confusing, that Dockerfile is clearly not the one you're using, and I'd also instead follow @DavidMaze's suggestion in using a virtual environment.

Comment: Are you using a workflow? Could it be that you are setting the ARG value from outside of your dockerfile and it gets overriden? If yes, please provide the workflow

Comment: @DavidGomes this is the docker file that i am using.

Answer (score 0):

For this setup, I would use a Python virtual environment.  This can sometimes be a little bit tricky in Docker – the `activate` script doesn't persist, a virtual environment is tied to a very specific Python installation – but it's easy enough to do.

A key here is that the two stages need to have the *exact* same image.  This can be a good place to use a build-time `ARG` to control it; even if you'll never change it externally, it does ensure that the two stages match.

```bash
# before any FROM lines
ARG BASE_IMAGE=python:3.10 # or your base-image:tag
```

In the first stage, create a virtual environment at a known path.  Use that virtual environment's `pip` and other tools to do installation.

```bash
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS stage1

# Create the virtual environment
RUN python3 -m venv /venv

# Stay out of the filesystem root directory
WORKDIR /app

# Do you need OS-level dependencies?
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
      build-essential

# Install package dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .

# Make sure to use the virtual environment's pip
RUN /venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In the second stage, copy the virtual environment.  You chose its name in the first stage, so it's not version-dependent.  The virtual environment must be at the same path in both stages.  It will help to set `$PATH` so the virtual environment comes first (this is one of the things the `activate` script does).  But from there, the rest of the Dockerfile can look the same as what you have now.

```bash
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
COPY --from=stage1 /venv /venv
ENV PATH=/venv/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR /my_dir
COPY ./ ./
CMD ["./my_script.sh"]
```